# How to make a js var in a function global to use it outside?

Tags: javascript

I want to make the "var id" in the function global. That i can use the value of it in the alert outside the function. Thats my code:

```html
<script>
function myFunctionGetCode() {
 
    
    
    var code = getInputVal('code'); //get value from Textinputfield from html
    var con = "/";
    var id = con+code;
    
}
     
      alert(id);
      
</script>
```

Comment: just move its declaration outside the function...

Comment: Thats does not work for me!

Comment: What is your final goal here? Can you be more clear? Because moving `id` declaration outside the function will thrown an alert showing `undefined`, since `id` only get some value when `myFunctionGetCode` is called... But it is global

Comment: Alternative solution: make `myFunctionGetCode()` return `id`, then do `alert(myFunctionGetCode());`.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specified what is your final goal or why are you trying to move `id` to a global scope, but you can do it by simple moving the `var id` (declaration) outside the function, then it will be global and accessible by all functions.

Obviously, the `alert` will show `"undefined"` since `id` only gets some value when the `myFunctionGetCode()` is called.

The code below shows this.

```js
var id;
function myFunctionGetCode() { 
    var code = getInputVal('code'); //get value from Textinputfield from html
    var con = "/";
    id = con+code;    
    console.log(id)
}     
alert(id);

function getInputVal(elemId){
  return document.getElementById(elemId).value;
}
```

```html
<input id="code"/>
<button onclick="myFunctionGetCode()">Get Id</button>
```

**BUT** if you want to throw the alert with the `id` value only when it gets some value then you should move the `alert()` inside the function. (You can still declare the `id` variable outside the function to let it global, or inside the function, as you currently have)

Open snippet to see:

```js
//var id; -> You can still declare it here (as global)
function myFunctionGetCode() { 
    var code = getInputVal('code'); 
    var con = "/";
    var id = con+code;  //or you can declare it here, but not global  
    alert(id);
}     

function getInputVal(elemId){
  return document.getElementById(elemId).value;
}
```

```html
<input id="code"/>
<button onclick="myFunctionGetCode()">Get Id</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

From your sample code I guess that you do not want to make your value global, but that you want to return a value - after all you are doing an operation inside your function that calculates a value from certain inputs.

So you would use the return keyword, and call the function to get the value:

```
<script>
function myFunctionGetCode() {
    var code = getInputVal('code'); //get value from Textinputfield from html
    var con = "/";
    var id = con+code;
    return id;
}

alert(myFunctionGetCode());

</script>
```

As a rule you do not want to make function variables global, since this means the value can be changed anywhere in your script or website, and that might lead to side effects and unexpected values in your function. If you need to pass something in use function parameters (or read from a text input like in your case), if you want to give back a result use return.

Answer (score 0):

Can you move the alert inside the function or return the "id" value from the function instead?

You can make the variable global by doing something like:
window.your_namespace.id = value;

and then access the variable in the same way:
value = window.your_namespace.id

but its best not to pass data around using the global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make var id to property of window object then you can access the id out side the function.

```
function myFunctionGetCode() {
  var code = getInputVal('code'); //get value from Textinputfield from html
  var con = "/";
  window.id = 10;// Change to this

}
myFunctionGetCode();
alert(id);
```